# How to display defects within a defect suite using a custom grid

Tags: rally

I have a scenario where I want to create a custom grid that shows all defects in my project that are linked to a specific defect suite.

Given that the relationship is from the defect suite to the defects (e.g. the defect suite has a collection of defects) how do I create a custom query within a custom grid that shows all defect related to that defect suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v2.0 of WS API we removed the ability to return child collections in the same response for performance reasons. In v2.0 fetching a collection will return an object with the count and the url from which to get the collection. It means that when we query on DefectSuite object its Defects collection is not returned.

As far as custom grids, Defects collection of DefectSuite is not available in the Columns on a custom grid when you choose DefectSuite in the Object dropdown.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/defect-suites-by-release) of a custom app that displays a grid of defect suites with associated defects. DefectSuites are filtered by release. You may copy/paste [this html file](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/defect-suites-by-release/blob/master/deploy/App.html) into a custom page in Rally.

The js file:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
    componentCls: 'app',
    scopeType: 'release',
    addContent: function() {
        this._makeStore();
    },
   onScopeChange: function() {
        console.log('onScopeChange');
        this._makeStore();
    },
_makeStore: function(){
        Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                model: 'DefectSuite',
                fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Defects', 'DefectStatus'],  
                pageSize: 100,
                autoLoad: true,
                filters: [this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getQueryFilter()],
                listeners: {
                    load: this._onDefectSuitesLoaded,
                    scope: this
                }
            }); 
    },
     _onDefectSuitesLoaded: function(store, data){
        var defectSuites = [];
        var pendingDefects = data.length;
         console.log(data.length);
         if (data.length ===0) {
            this._createDefectSuitesGrid(defectSuites);  
         }
         Ext.Array.each(data, function(defectsuite){ 
            var ds  = {
                FormattedID: defectsuite.get('FormattedID'),   
                _ref: defectsuite.get('_ref'),  
                DefectStatus: defectsuite.get('DefectStatus'),
                DefectCount: defectsuite.get('Defects').Count,
                Defects: []
            };
            var defects = defectsuite.getCollection('Defects');
            defects.load({
                                fetch: ['FormattedID'],
                                callback: function(records, operation, success){
                                    Ext.Array.each(records, function(defect){
                                        ds.Defects.push({_ref: defect.get('_ref'),
                                                        FormattedID: defect.get('FormattedID')
                                                    });
                                    }, this);
                                    --pendingDefects;
                                    if (pendingDefects === 0) {
                                        this._createDefectSuitesGrid(defectSuites);
                                    }
                                },
                                scope: this
                            });
            defectSuites.push(ds);
     },this);
 },

      _createDefectSuitesGrid: function(defectsuites) {
        var defectSuiteStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                data: defectsuites,
                pageSize: 100,  
            });
        if (!this.down('#defectsuitegrid')) {
         this.grid = this.add({
            xtype: 'rallygrid',
            itemId: 'defectsuitegrid',
            store: defectSuiteStore,
            columnCfgs: [
                {
                   text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                    tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
                },
                {
                    text: 'Defect Count', dataIndex: 'DefectCount',
                },
                {
                    text: 'Defect Status', dataIndex: 'DefectStatus',flex:1
                },
                {
                    text: 'Defects', dataIndex: 'Defects',flex:1, 
                    renderer: function(value) {
                        var html = [];
                        Ext.Array.each(value, function(defect){
                            html.push('<a href="' + Rally.nav.Manager.getDetailUrl(defect) + '">' + defect.FormattedID + '</a>')
                        });
                        return html.join(', ');
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
         }else{
            this.grid.reconfigure(defectSuiteStore);
         }
    }
});
```